# Laravel lazy load optimisation

Tags: php, laravel, orm, query-optimization, eloquent

I want to load all my comments with one query, for now I have Forum Thread and Replies and comments for both, so I eager load comments seperatly.

```
$threads = Thread::with('comments');
$replies = Reply::with('comments');
```

may be something like:

```
Comment::loadFor([$threads, $replies]);
```

Comment: $comments = Comment::with(['forum', 'reply'])->get();

Follow @werewolf's example below as to how to setup the relationships. Also be sure to read the docs on relationships as it's all there.

Comment: You can't do that with single query using Eloquent methods, since it's executing separate queries for each relation. Optimisation in your case would be caching.

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared relations in your `Comment` model for both then You may try this:

```
$comments = Comment::with('threads', 'replies')->get();
```

In this case, you need to create relation methods, i.e. `threads` and `replies` in your `Comment` model, for example:

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Reply', 'comment_id', 'id'); // Could be different
}

public function threads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Thread', 'comment_id', 'id'); // Could be different
}
```

Comment: I see, going from behind. It wont work, i need to find the thread first!

Comment: Well, I need to find the thread first, then get its relations. The problem is that comments table queried twice, and as I see Its good enough. Would be nice to have a method that allows for fewer queries tho.

Comment: Can you please provide your relationship methods, how they are related to each other.